# Terraform ec2 userdata evaluation problem

Tags: shell, terraform

I'm having trouble in putting userdata shell script to ec2 in startup process. I'm trying to run init.sh script when initializing my ec2 instance, with the terraform code below.

```
resource "aws_instance" "myinstance" {
  ...
  user_data = base64encode(templatefile(
    "${path.module}/templates/init.sh", {
      ...
      ADDITIONAL_IPS  = var.additional_ips
    }
    )
  )
```

I have a `init.sh` as below,

```
ADDITIONAL_IPS="${ADDITIONAL_IPS}"
NLB_EIPS=()
for IP in $ADDITIONAL_IPS; do
  NLB_EIPS+=" -p $${IP} 255.255.255.255"
done
```

However, when I create EC2 instance and check `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`, I see the result below.

```
+ ADDITIONAL_IPS='1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3'
+ NLB_EIPS=()
+ for IP in $ADDITIONAL_IPS
+ NLB_EIPS+=' -p 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3 255.255.255.255'
```

The shell script below is the result I want to achieve,

```
#!/bin/bash

ADDITIONAL_IPS="1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 3.3.3.3"
NLB_EIPS=()
for IP in $ADDITIONAL_IPS; do
  NLB_EIPS+=" -p $IP 255.255.255.255"
done

echo ${NLB_EIPS[@]}
```

Result of the shell script above(And also intended result): `-p 1.1.1.1 255.255.255.255 -p 2.2.2.2 255.255.255.255 -p 3.3.3.3 255.255.255.255`

Just running the shell script loops successfully, but using Terraform seems to evaluate IP variable as the `$ADDITIONAL_IPS` itself.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: I can see in the documentation that the `user_data` is for a valid UTF8 string, instead the `user_data_base64` is for encoded text, so first of all try to change this parameter.

[aws_instance user_data_base64](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/instance#user_data_base64)

Comment: If you want to substitute the value in the template file with the variables provided, you can drop the quotation marks from the `ADDITIONAL_IPS="${ADDITIONAL_IPS}"`.  Also, if you are using the same variable name and value in the `for` loop you can just use it directly: `for IP in ${ADDITIONAL_IPS}`.

Comment: @DaniloCacace Same result, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

[templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/templatefile) function does interpolate Terraform variables between `${` and `}` like `${VAR}`. It will not touch `$VAR` (without curly braces). So you had that almost right, in your case this should work:

```
ADDITIONAL_IPS="${ADDITIONAL_IPS}"
NLB_EIPS=()
for IP in $ADDITIONAL_IPS; do
  NLB_EIPS+=" -p $IP 255.255.255.255"
done
```